# Inserting the MacTeX logo into a document

Tags: macros, mactex, logos

What is the MacTeX equivalent of `\LaTeX`? `\MacTeX` doesn't work.

Comment: There is no official logo; `Mac\TeX{}` could do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no official logo for MacTeX. Using

```
Mac\TeX
```

should do.